# Golang: Computing Anti-log of a number

Tags: go, logarithm

I wanted to know how it is that you compute the anti-log of a number.

Comment: The opposite of a logarithm is called a power or an exponent in maths.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Will. I do not want to throw an excuse, but I was taught to use anti-log in middle school, in India.

Comment: Cool. Learn something new every day.

Comment: Thanks Will. I am not sure what your opinion of 'new' in this context is.

Comment: I was meaning that you have taught me a new mathematical term. I thought you just didn't know the word, but it turned out that I was wrong. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Using [Pow10()](http://golang.org/pkg/math/#Pow10) or [Pow()](http://golang.org/pkg/math/#Pow) depending on the base of your logarithm.

if  `a = log b (base10)`, then the anti-log of `a` to the base 10 is `b`

Comment: Thanks Mitch, I am not sure if I can make use of those functions directly. Are you suggesting that I employ high-school math. I employed basic high-school match and shifted the log to exponential and found what I needed. The answer is OK upto the 10 or 11th decimal point.

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "math"
)

func main() {
        for f := 1.0; f < 10; f *= 1.1 {
                fmt.Printf("10^%15f == %18f\n", f, math.Pow(10, f))
        }
}
```

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/oZKFx_Pk1k)

---

Output

```
10^       1.000000 ==          10.000000
10^       1.100000 ==          12.589254
10^       1.210000 ==          16.218101
10^       1.331000 ==          21.428906
10^       1.464100 ==          29.113874
10^       1.610510 ==          40.785895
10^       1.771561 ==          59.096397
10^       1.948717 ==          88.862208
10^       2.143589 ==         139.183839
10^       2.357948 ==         228.006743
10^       2.593742 ==         392.412163
10^       2.853117 ==         713.044618
10^       3.138428 ==        1375.397963
10^       3.452271 ==        2833.160736
10^       3.797498 ==        6273.332921
10^       4.177248 ==       15040.011538
10^       4.594973 ==       39352.559693
10^       5.054470 ==      113362.727116
10^       5.559917 ==      363008.933932
10^       6.115909 ==     1305897.362804
10^       6.727500 ==     5339492.112719
10^       7.400250 ==    25133324.832458
10^       8.140275 ==   138125842.074790
10^       8.954302 ==   900124188.827650
10^       9.849733 ==  7075101518.596476
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, jnml. I realized that manipulation of basic middle/high-school math was enough to do this.